# Using the Excel Filter function to display each row of a table, if any unique values in two columns match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have two worksheets with large tables (A and B). Both have unique identifier values in Colum M. WorksheetA2 is being filtered to show dates between two date ranges (example below). WorksheetB2 I want to look up the unique identifiers in WorksheetA2 (column M), see if any of them match the unique identifiers in WorksheetB (column M), and if they do return each row where there's a match.

Happy to solve this in VBA if that's a better option for what I'm trying to do here.

This code for WorksheetA2 works fine:

```
=IF(DateFrom="","no dates found",(SORT(FILTER(WoorksheetA,(WoorksheetA Dates>=DateFrom)*(Worksheet A Dates<=DateTo),"no dates found"))))
```

This code returns #VALUE!:

```
=IF(DateFrom="","no dates found",(SORT(FILTER('WoorksheetB,(WoorksheetB Dates>=DateFrom)*(WorksheetA2 M:M=WorksheetB M:M),"no dates found"))))
```

```
=IF(DateFrom="","no dates found",(SORT(FILTER('Post Data'!A2:M9000,('Post Data'!A2:A9000>=Output!D3)*(UniqueIDPre = 'Post Data'!M:M),"no dates found"))))
```

Comment: Please check this and update your question accordingly: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Be consistent in the name of your worksheet. Your question mentions Worksheet, while your calculation mentions a mix of that and Wo**o**rksheet. Also add data in markdown table format so we can reproduce something.